# Database adding In Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I am trying to make a project of student information. There i am trying to add 
SQL database. But When i ran the program i am having some network-related problem.

Thrown:

```
"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)" (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException) Exception Message = "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)", Exception Type = "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException", Exception WinRT Data = ""
```

I am getting this message.

Comment: It could be due to any reason...wrong connection string etc..How are you trying to connect to database??

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the connection. Could be incorrect connection string, or could be an issues with SQL server. Try connecting with server explorer.

Comment: Do you get this error in SQL Management Studio or in Visual Studio ?

Comment: You can try this : In SQL Server Configuration Manager window on the left side select the option SQL Server Services and on the right side check the service SQL Server(MSSQLSERVER) is stopped or running . If this service is stopped then right click on this service and then start this service.

Comment: The error gives me in Visual studio. When i created the database i checked whether it is connected or not. I pressed Test Connected and It showed that connection Successful.

con = new SqlConnection("data source=OrNoK;Integrated Security=Yes;Database=master");  

         
 The error is showing because of da.Fill(ds) this line.

Comment: con = new SqlConnection("data source=OrNoK;Integrated Security=Yes;Database=master");
            da = new SqlDataAdapter("insert into studentdetail1 values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "')", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

This is the code that i have used for connection

Comment: And this is the connection String
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\FuRiOuS\Documents\Studentdetail.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Comment: `INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)`

Firtsly your sql command should be so.

Comment: And When you add values you don't need quotes.
`values(textBox1.Text , textBox2.Text ,textBox3.Text ,textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text ,textBox6.Text )`

Comment: And try this :
`connectionstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\FuRiOuS\Documents\Studentdetail‌​.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"`